# Do I need to create the Document() object every time I read a new document and index it in LUCENE.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene

As the title suggests, or do I reuse the document object on every file that I read and then send it off to the index?

Currently I am doing this

```
  // Loop for each file
        document = new Document();
        fileData = // Read file contents
        document.Add(new Field("text", fileData, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED,    Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
        indexWriter.AddDocument(document);                                                                                                                        
    // end loop
```

For each file I read. Is this the correct approach?

Thanks

Comment: Why, is it a performance issue creating it every time?

Comment: @PeterLillevold, Yes I am creating the document object every time for a new file I read.

Comment: But is it a performance issue creating it?

Comment: @SimonSvensson I am not really sure. I have not done performance tests. What I was thinking that you create a document object and set the fields. On each file read, you update the documents file content part only. That is what I was thinking. I might be completely wrong.

Comment: You will find the cost of new'ing up the document class insignificant when compared to lucene indexing the document, no need to worry about a premature optimization in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you experience performance issues, creating a document each time is the correct approach. After all, the bulk time is used in reading the actual file, which you will have to do either way. Saving a few cycles on instantiating a new `Document` is probably not going to have a big impact.

I would also be wary of reusing this object. Since it represents one file, reusing it on a different file could "leak" data between documents.